# Keyboard sometimes doesn't register some keys on home Lenovo Yoga

Tags: laptop, keyboard, hardware-failure

For the last little while, I've had an infuriating issue where the <kbd>`</kbd>, <kbd>1</kbd>, <kbd>q</kbd>, <kbd>Esc</kbd>, and <kbd>Tab</kbd> keys don't register key presses. For example, I sometimes hold down both <kbd>`</kbd> and <kbd>1</kbd> for several seconds and get a string of both <kbd>`</kbd> and <kbd>1</kbd> in odd permutations, like in:

> `1`````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````1`````1`1`1`1`1``11111111``1```1```11``1`1``1`1````1`11111111111111111111````1`1``1`1`1`1`````1```````` (held down for a solid 10 seconds at least)

Other times the keys will work perfectly normally for extended periods. The effect seems to be worsened when using another key at the same time (usually alt for when I'm trying to <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> around). It should be noted that all five keys are in the same general area. I use a Lenovo Yoga that I haven't opened up at all. It may also affect my <kbd>F1</kbd> key but I rarely use that enough to know for sure.

My hypothesis is that at some point I got some food or something in the keyboard, but I don't know for sure as I mostly work with software.

Comment: If you connect an external USB keyboard, does the issue persist?

Comment: It's hard to say given how sporadic this issue is -- it works fine for extended periods and then has bouts of infuriation -- but from what admittedly very little testing I have done, the issue does not persist. That said, permanently using an external keyboard is not an option for me.

Comment: Are you on a domain network?  If so, have you tried testing on a local user account or in safe mode without networking?  Also, check if `wuauserv` might be active when it occurs?  I've experienced similar issues at the workplace, but have yet to isolate the root cause.

Comment: Might still be related to `wqauserv` issue, what's your available bandwidth from ISP?

Comment: Just using speedtest.net I run a 6ms ping, 301.91 mbps download, and 365.35 mbps upload.

Comment: As the intermittent keys are all grouped together, assume track fail. If this is on a laptop, also suspect swollen battery.

Comment: btw, if you'd formatted your 'test text' as code you wouldn't have had to escape every character ;)